# i am having problems bootstrap popup or iframe pdf

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, pdf

**As you can see in internet explorer bootstrap popup is not working fine.**

Check ie screenshot example, please.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_tutorial.pdf" width="100%" height="375" type='application/pdf' style="margin-top:150px;"></iframe>
      <div class="container">
         <h2>Modal Example</h2>
         <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
         <!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <!-- Modal content-->
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: ie9 output screenshot]

[image: Chrome output screenshot]
How to solve this problem? Appreciate any help.

Comment: try my code, i have checked in ie too, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reccomend a different approach :
Embed the pdf using Google PDF viewer which uses javascript like so :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_tutorial.pdf&embedded=true" width="100%" height="375" type='application/pdf' style="margin-top:150px;">
</iframe>
  <div class="container">
     <h2>Modal Example</h2>
     <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested successfuly on explorer and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

just add this script in your code, it works fine with ie too, try this

```js
<!--add this code in your file with script tag -->
$(document).ready(function (){
$('iframe').each(function(){
var url = $(this).attr("src");
$(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
});
});
<!--add this code in your file with script tag -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_tutorial.pdf" width="100%" height="375" type='application/pdf' style="margin-top:150px;"></iframe>
      <div class="container">
         <h2>Modal Example</h2>
         <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
         <!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
               <!-- Modal content-->
               <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```